# Running Java from ASP.NET MVC doesn't work

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to run Java code from cmd, it works. But when I run it from ASP.NET MVC application, I always get:
Cannot find or load main.
This is the code I'm using:

```
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java.exe";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "E:/Atypon/TE1/src/Assignment3.DateTest";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.Start();
            string result = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you did not provide it with complete file name. Usually java runnables' files end with either `.class` or `.jar`.

Comment: Adding the extension is one of the causes of this error when running java from cmd. But I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Before running it in C#, what happens if you just execute it at the command line? `"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java.exe" E:/Atypon/TE1/src/Assignment3.DateTest` Get that working first before trying to do it from C#.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Even though if I use `java E:/Atypon/TE1/src/Assignment3.DateTest `, it works.( if I use it from the Java program directory).

Comment: Can you just use the latter version that works?

Comment: This version works from cmd, but not from ASP.NET process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to specify the path to main class in the working directory , not Arguments:

```
 public ActionResult Run()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java.exe";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //path to dir
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:/Atypon/TE1/src";
        //packageName.MainClass
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "Assignment3.DateTest";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.Start();
        string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        return View("Index",(Object)result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the paramters be wrong for the class name, perhaps it should be

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "E:/Atypon/TE1/src/Assignment3.DateTest.class";
```

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Actually, I once read that adding .class generates this error.